# What is the appropriate regex string to match a specific html element?

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I have a ton of text replacements to make and I would like to try and do this all at once instead of manually.  I'm trying to replace `<a class='stuff morestuff' href='#'>Some Text</a>` with `Some Text`; essentially stripping off the surrounding anchor tag.

I've been messing around with a search/replace in Visual Studio using regex, but am not really getting anywhere.  My latest attempt:

Find what:
    `\<a class='stuff morestuff' href='#'\>(.+)\<\/a\>`

Replace with:
    `$1`

**If what I want to do is even feasible, how can I correct my regex to accomplish this?**

Comment: which language?for REGEX it is imp to tag it with the language

Comment: I should add that I'm doing this in the Visual Studio IDE using the Find and Replace dialog.

Comment: in any case the `regex` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will match your anchors if the class and href are always the same:

```
Find: \<a[^\>]class='stuff morestuff' href='\#'[^\>]*\>(.*)\</a\>
Replace: $1
```

This regex will replace all the anchors with the inner text:

```
Find: \<a[^\>]*\>(.*)\</a\>
Replace: $1
```

I'm assuming from your post you plan to use this in Visual Studio's Find/Replace and not in code.

Comment: Not that this isn't useful, but this matches *all* anchors, I'm looking to be more specific and match on the `class` and `href` attributes.

Comment: So you only want to replace the anchors with the two classes shown that also have href of "#" ? Are class and href always the same and always in that order?

Comment: That's correct. There are other anchors throughout the project that I don't want to strip.

Comment: You could use  \<a[^\>]class='stuff morestuff' href='#'[^\>]*\>(.*)\</a\>

Comment: I tried `\<a[^\>]class='stuff morestuff' href='#'[^\>]*\>(.*)\</a\>` and various modifications, but can't get it to match any of the elements.

Comment: Oh I see. The # needs to be escaped too. I was using the VS power tools search. Updated my answer again. This one works in the standard find/replace.

Comment: This works!  However, I had to replace the `()` with `{}`, and instead of using `$1`, it was `\1`.  Some Visual Studio-specific quirks, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Find:`\\<a class='.*?' href='#'>(.*?)\\</a\\>`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I couldn't get it to match anything.

Comment: The > after in href='#'> needs a \ before it. Escaping the '\'s shouldn't be necessary in VS.